# How to use LIKE in a t-sql dynamic statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use the LIKE keyword with the % wildcards wrapping the parameter, but I'm not sure how to get the % characters into the statement without breaking it. Right now I have:

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE %@search%'
```

I get a SqlException error in my .net app that says "Incorrect syntax near '@search' when I run it. The error goes away if I remove the % characters surrounding the @search parameter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The % characters have to be *in* the search string...

```
SET @search = '%' + @search + '%'
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE @search'
```

Note that the following would also work, but introduces potential for a SQL injection vulnerability...

```
-- DON'T do this!
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'''
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * from [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE ''%'' + @search + ''%'''
exec sp_executesql @query=@SQLQuery, @params=N'@search nvarchar(96)', @search=@search
```

The only difference from this version as compared to the others is that the dynamic execution of the sql is in fact parameterized which mitigates sql injection a bit.

Comment: in my case, this part should be like:  N'%' + @search + '%' - no need for extra single quotation

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @search = '%' + @search 
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE ' + @search + '%'
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me!

```
SET @search = '''%' + @search + '%'''
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [tblApps] WHERE [firstName] LIKE' + @search
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: This doesn't parameterize the `@search` variable, and is subject to SQL Injection attacks. It's the same as the *Don't do this* section of AvPinzur's Answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
declare @Cmd nvarchar(2000)
declare @eName varchar(10)
set @eName='a'
set @Cmd= 'select * from customer1 where name LIKE '''+'%' +@eName+ '%' + ''''
print @Cmd
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd
```

Comment: i was going to down vote,  but changed my mind, simply put: your approach is working but it's open to sql injection