# Sending Paramaters To Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for the query in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aaa3/1
The parameters are EmpId and EmpName. The query works fine.
When the parameters are delared inside '@query' part, the 'Execute Stored Procedure' doesnt prompt to enter parameters. 
When declard outside '@query', I get the option to send parameters but it always returns all rows irrespective of the filter.

So.....Is this the right way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeLeaves
BEGIN
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)             

 SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(LeaveName) 
                from tblLeaveType
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

   SET @query = '
                 DECLARE @EmpId uniqueidentifier = null,   
                         @EmpName nvarchar(50) = null
                 IF @EmpId ='+'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'+'
                 SET @EmpId = NULL
                 IF @EmpName = '+''+'
                 SET @EmpName = NULL
                 SELECT EmpId, EmpName,' + @cols + ' 
                 FROM 
                 (
                  SELECT E.EmpId, E.EmpName, T.LeaveName, L.Days 
                  FROM tblEmp E
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEmpLeaves L ON E.EmpId = L.EmpId                
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLeaveType T ON L.TypeId = T.TypeId
                  WHERE
                  (E.EmpId = @EmpId OR @EmpId IS NULL)AND
                  (E.EmpNameLIKE %@EmpName% OR @EmpName IS NULL)                
                 ) x
                PIVOT
                 (
                  MAX(Days) FOR LeaveName IN (' + @cols + ')                      
                 ) p 
               ORDER BY EmpId'
               execute  sp_executesql @query;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

These links helped me resolve this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

[How to use LIKE in a t-sql dynamic statement in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383634/how-to-use-like-in-a-t-sql-dynamic-statement-in-a-stored-procedure)