# SQL Server dynamic stored procedure - passing parameter value to like search

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a `users` table with `categories` column with delimited values.

I'm trying to pass a category and perform a like search with the users table in dynamic SQL.

The category value is paramterized.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParamDef AS NVARCHAR(2000) 

SET @ParamDef = '@category VARCHAR(100)'

SET @SQLQuery = 'UPDATE [U]
                 SET [U].[status] = 1
                 FROM [dbo].[users] AS [U]
                 WHERE [U].[categories] LIKE ??

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQuery ,@ParamDef ,@category
```

I want my like search to check **%,@category,%**

Comment: Got the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383634/how-to-use-like-in-a-t-sql-dynamic-statement-in-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

did you try to form the query like this?

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParamDef AS NVARCHAR(2000) 

SET @ParamDef = '@category VARCHAR(100)'

SET @SQLQuery = 'UPDATE [U]
             SET [U].[status] = 1
             FROM [dbo].[users] AS [U]
             WHERE [U].[categories] LIKE '''+ '%' + @category + '%' + ''''

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQuery ,@ParamDef ,@category
```

please let me know if this helps.
Thanks
Ashraf

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use dynamic SQL?  It's susceptible to SQL injection, especially if you're using @category from your UI.

You can instead use the following to accomplish the same:

```
DECLARE @category VARCHAR(100)

UPDATE [U]
SET [U].[status] = 1
FROM [dbo].[users] AS [U]
WHERE [U].[categories] LIKE '%,' + @category + ',%'
```

Otherwise, it looks like you've found your solution using dynamic SQL.