# free text search not giving correct output with two or more dots with contains

Tags: sql, contains, freetext

I have the code below :

```
declare @searchText varchAr(150)='"*a.b.me@gmail.com*"'
select * from account a
WHERE
CONTAINS ((aEmail,), @searchText)
```

it is not showing any result .

Comment: can you specify, which SQL server you are working on?

Comment: also what you're trying to do

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383634/how-to-use-like-in-a-t-sql-dynamic-statement-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: use *contains* as... `CONTAINS (aEmail, @searchText) `